# Can't use uuid and create an extension to use it

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.04

I want to use uuid in Postgresql 9.2 on Ubuntu 13. So when I tried to check whether is available or not, I did:

```
select uuid_generate_v4() as one;
```

And it gave me `ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist`

Then I did `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";`

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
```

Well, what do I do next?

By the way, `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;` returns `plpsql (1.0)` only.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The operating system package that contains the extension is not installed.  To install it:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.2
```

Comment: I ended up using a more generic package, postgresql-contrib, which I think maps to your current version. That also worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone using the [asdf version manager](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) with the [asdf-postgres plugin](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres), installing postgres versions as follows fixes this issue:

```sh
POSTGRES_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--with-uuid=e2fs asdf install postgres <VERSION>
```

Comment: For me this also required a `sudo apt install uuid-dev`, otherwise what a lifesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For you guys, who installed postgres using postgres rpm repo on Fedora or similar distro:

> sudo dnf install postgresql-contrib

installs a package from default fedora repo, which conflicts with postgres, like:

> /usr/pgsql-12/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)

Right way is

> sudo dnf install postgresql12-contrib

You can double check it during install, it has to be from pgdg12, same as postgresql-server

(you have insert your postgres version instead of '12')

Answer (score 1):

If you still get the error, try to run manually the two SQL files inside `/usr/share/postgresql/9.X/extension/uuid-ossp*.sql` into your database