# Ansible task fails, when creating extensions

Tags: ansible

While provisioning via Vagrant and Ansible I keep running into this issue.

> TASK [postgresql : Create extensions] ******************************************
>   failed: [myapp] (item=postgresql_extensions) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "psql myapp -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgresql_extensions;'", "delta": "0:00:00.037786", "end": "2017-04-01 08:37:34.805325", "failed": true, "item": "postgresql_extensions", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-04-01 08:37:34.767539", "stderr": "ERROR:  could not open extension control file \"/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgresql_extensions.control\": No such file or directory", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

I'm using a [railsbox.io](https://railsbox.io) generated [playbook](https://railsbox.io/boxes/253c1eb90ccb).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use uuid and create an extension to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810921/cant-use-uuid-and-create-an-extension-to-use-it)

Comment: Why was this question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that railsbox.io is still using a deprecated syntax in the task.

```
- name: Create extensions
  sudo_user: '{{ postgresql_admin_user }}'
  shell: "psql {{ postgresql_db_name }} -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS {{ item }};'"
  with_items: postgresql_extensions
  when: postgresql_extensions
```

The last line should use full jinja2 syntax.

```
when: '{{postgresql_extensions}}'
```